# Using UnderscoreJS function in cakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, underscore.js

I've coded my project with cakePHP and now I need to filter a list of objects.
This is a piece of my code

```
<?php foreach ($objects as $object): ?>
            .............
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Before this part of code there is a html `input` tag to perform search on an single field of `$objects`. I would use underscore library to perform this kind of operations.

I've found some implementations of underscore.js in PHP, but I don't know if I can use this in my view file,  which has `.ctp` extension.

Anybody has some solution or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly what you're after is [array filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

you would use it like so:

```
$filtered = array_filter($objects, function( $obj ) {
    return $obj->property === 'someValue';
});
```

Any value of $obj that returns true will be stored into `$filtered`.

Comment: Well, but I need to perform this kind of operation every-time user tip a char into search box above code in question.This is possible?

Comment: You'll need to pass the search to the server from your user's browser, probably with an ajax call to a seperate php script, filter the objects with array_filter and return the appropriate data to the client. This is a decent tutorial on ajax using jquery http://www.elated.com/articles/ajax-with-jquery-a-beginners-guide/

Comment: Unless the objects are generating some html you want to filter, in which case you could use underscore, could you post more of the surrounding code?